# How to use the same ImageView in 2 activity

Tags: java, android, mobile, imageview, android-imageview

[image: How to use the same ImageView in 2 activities]

Is it possible to use two ImageViews in two activities at the same time? does everything that happens with one ImageView happen with the other?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use two ImageViews in two activities at the same time?

only one activity is ever present, the other will be in the background, but sure, you can use the ***same image resource inside multiple image views*** on multiple activities. They are not the same instance of an image view, but they do use the same ***image resource***. which means that:

> does everything that happens with one ImageView happen with the other?

is a no.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

When the app changes the activity from activity 1 too 2 you can not be certain that the old activity might be cleared up by the os. You have to store the changes in a different way and apply them to the activities once the start.

This feels like you don't really need two different activies. Can you further discribe what you want to achive?

Comment: I need to show in ViewHolder the art of the music that is inside your folders